# adding ToC prevents using custom LoF

Tags: tocloft

I'm trying to make a document with the following structure:

- front matter (cover, etc)
- ToC (regular, no customization)
- text
- LoF (customized)
- Figures

The issue: If I add a table of contents, the customized list of figures looses all customization (including section names). If I remove the ToC, my custom LoF is produced as desired.

here is a MWE:

```
%%%---- preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,draft]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=period,figurename=Doc.,figurewithin=section,font=normal]{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{secdot}
\sectiondot{section}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\centering}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}


%%%---- document
\begin{document}


%%%---- regular ToC
% \begin{small}\tableofcontents\end{small}


%%%---- main text
\section{sec1} 
some text...



%%%---- custom LoF
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2em}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsubsection}
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vspace*{0.25\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecafterpnum}{\vspace*{0.25\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{8pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{8pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{\cftsubsecindent}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Doc. }

\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{8pt}
\begin{small}\listoffigures\end{small}

\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\voffset}{-1cm}
\renewcommand{\floatsep}{0.5cm}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}


%%%---- figures
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{sec1}
\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{\protect\numberline{\textbf{\thesection.}} {sec1}}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{fig caption}
% \includegraphics[height=0.99\textheight,keepaspectratio]{*.png}
\label{fig_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

So it seems that I need to do something after inserting the ToC, but I can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Your `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` results in a global setting of `tocdepth` to 0 from reading the `toc` file. So it is still valid for the `lof` (and the `lot`). Either replace it by `\value{tocdepth}=0\relax` or add `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}` (and maybe the same with `lot` instead of `lof`).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that it would set `tocdepth` globally. I added `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}` and now I have both the ToC and LoF correct.